# jQuery disable dropdownlist item by text

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a asp:net dropdownlist which has extra items appended server side:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlResult" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="-- Please Select --"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

...and basically I would like to disable/enable an entry by the display text in jQuery. I've tried the numerous examples on here but none of them seem to work for me. eg.

```
$("#ddlResult option[text='Positive']").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

..or...

```
$("#ddlResult option[text='Positive']").hide();
```

...or ...

```
$("#<% =ddlResult.ClientID %> > option[text='Positive']").attr("disabled", "disabled")
```

...amongst others.

Can anyone advise where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be something like this. You can use the [:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to find the text and disable the option.

```
$('#ddlResult option:contains("Positive")').prop("disabled", true);
```

**or**

```
$('#ddlResult option:contains("Positive")').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

**Working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b2wague8/)**

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using 

 `$("[id$='_ddlResult'] option:contains('Positive')").attr("disabled", true)`
 
...as I'm stuck on v1.5. And interestingly I just needed `.attr("disabled", false)` to re-enable the option.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use the `filter` method to select the correct `option` element and then `hide` or `disable` as follows:

```
 $("#ddlResult option").filter(function() { 
      return $(this).text().trim() == 'Positive'; 
 }).hide();
```

---

```
 $("#ddlResult option").filter(function() { 
      return $(this).text().trim() == 'Positive'; 
 }).prop('disabled',true);
```

Please note that to toggle between enabled and disabled you would have to use `.prop()` -- recommended:

```
1. .prop('disabled',false); //to enable
2. .prop('disabled',true); //to disable
```

If you choose to use `.attr('disabled', '..anything..')` to disable, you have to use `.removeAttr('disabled')` to enable.

Comment: Thanks, I since realised that I'm on v1.5 so couldn't use prop. My exact solution was - `$("[id$='_ddlResult'] option:contains('Positive')").attr("disabled", true)`

Answer (score 0):

try bellow pattern

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#<%=DropdownListId.ClientId%> option[value='1']").attr("disabled","disabled");

});